# Can't find syncthing-gtk in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10

I've just upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10. I had syncthing and syncthing-gtk installed before the upgrade. syncthing is still there, but syncthing-gtk has been removed, and neither apt nor flatpak can find it to reinstall it. Anyone know what happened to it?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it seems dropped even from last release of Debian.

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=syncthing-gtk&searchon=names
- https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=syncthing-gtk&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

No guarantee, but you may give a try to:

- Old [`.deb` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/syncthing-gtk/download) from Focal 20.04.
- [`.AppImage` package](https://github.com/kozec/syncthing-gtk/releases) from upstream project.